# two object connected by a spring : momentum/energy topic

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, momentum, spring

Here is my question below:

Question

---

Two objects A and B, connected by a light elastic spring with elastic constant 5.0 N/m, are initially at rest.
The mass A is 2.0 kg and the mass B is 1.0 kg.

Object B is hit by a hammer and moves away from A with an initial velocity of 10.0 m/s.

a) Find the velocity of object A when object B is momentarily at rest.

b) Find the extension of the spring when object B is momentarily at rest.

---

Here is my approach for this:
I use basic conservation of momentum(this is a 1-D problem).
The before momentum equation, object A is zero, hence we just have momentum of B at the instant it is hit by the hammer.
The after state momentum equation is just object A, while B is now zero.

Solving for the velocity of A gives v= 5m/s.
SO that is how part a) is answered.

For part b) I use energy equations,
I set kinetic energy of A, from the after state equal to the potential energy Hooke's law:
So (1/2)*m*v^2 =  (1/2)*k*(deltaX)^2
Solving for deltaX gives,
deltaX = sqrt(10) = 3.16 meters.

So my problem with my solutions, is that I feel that the amount of stretch of the spring does not feel right, I feel this is too large an amount.

I am hoping someone can take a look and let me know if there is a problem with my solution.

Regards.

Comment: Note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic). This applies to your previous question as well.

Comment: Hi John, I am putting down my approaches to the problem, and trying to get feedback on if the approach is proper or if I missed an idea. I looked at the Meta post you put, and in this regard, and there seems to be no consensus. And in the meta, they have some criteria about what the person writing should demonstrate. SO I am not sure about your post for me to look at the Meta post. Thanks for your reply on the previous question.

Comment: I'm not sure, but is it right to ask the extension in the very moment is being hit? It doesn't seem right to me because in the moment is hit it hasn't had time to move.

Comment: Hi Pablo, I think you did not get the right idea. It will get hit then it will keep moving until it comes to rest again due to the spring. But during the time object B got hit until it slowed down back to rest, the spring got extended. So it is NOT at the moment that B got hit.

Comment: @Palu ohh hahahaha thats another thing. Maybe you can try to make the lagrangian to derive the equations of motion.

Comment: Hi, yes I know, I took Advanced Classical Mechanics and did Lagrangian Mechanics in University. But this is Highschool level physics, algebra based, NO calculus allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first part was correct; but for the second part, you have to equate the energy of A plus the stored energy in the spring to the energy of B (because you start with no energy in the spring, and all the energy as kinetic energy in B).

So the expression for the stored energy is $E_\mathrm{spring}=\frac12 k x^2 = \frac12 m_b v_b^2 - \frac12 m_a v_a^2$.

In terms of momentum, it becomes

$$E_\mathrm{spring}=\frac12 k x^2=\frac{p^2}{2}\left(\frac{1}{m_b}-\frac{1}{m_a}\right)$$

That's a positive numbe. Note that if the mass of $b$ Is greater than the mass of $a$, then $b$ never stops (which is why you can get the apparent negative square root). Either way, for the conditions given the value of the extension is rather large.

It's good that you said "the answer doesn't feel right". That's an important step in solving real-world problems. Unfortunately, since the KE of A is exactly half the KE of B, getting the expression right still gets you to the "slightly unphysical" answer. That is because the spring constant is really very small (it will stretch a full meter when you hang a 500 gram mass from it).

Comment: Hi Floris, Thank you for your reply. I was thinking along those lines actually. SO due to you verbalizing it in detail, the issue is that when object B reaches rest momentarily, the object A should be in motion, because when B moves via the spring, it pulls on A. And when B goes to rest its vb=0 and va=5. So based on plugging into your equation above we get the spring energy = - KE of a,, so we run into a complex number. This is really amazing how this question seems to get stranger the deeper we go into it.

Comment: Hi John Rennie and others. I don't know why you guys put this on hold. I put my own solution, showed that I did work, but was uncertain if my logic would be correct. I am NOT a highschool student. I am someone who has a couple of degrees in science and engineering, but I like to challenge myself in solving problems and having  discussions. I like to think that forums such as this are Open-Free cultures of education where people can get into great academic discussions. I want to be apart of something like the Ancient Greek Philosophers. Free to discuss.

Comment: I don't understand this culture at Stackoverflow, having so many odd conditions to post questions. As long as people want to politely discuss philosophical ideas, science ideas, why create so much bureaucracy. Are people paid to create  bureaucracy at Stackoverflow? I want to understand if Stackoverflow is a Business with profit motives or if Stackoverflow is a Free-Open Forum not for Profit. If this Stackoverflow is modeled as a business, and hence for Profit, I can see why there would be need to generate this kind of  bureaucracy.

Comment: I thought that Stackoverflow was a created by academic people who like to share, who liked to solve problems. I had a belief that Stackoverflow was open like the Hippie movement of the 1960's, so Academic Hippies!

Comment: @Palu I updated the answer to show there is no complex number here... Also I'm not sure people here necessarily want to be called hippies. Did you get your answer? Then the system works.

Comment: Hi, I just saw your answer.And it seems it really requires a lot of rearranging, as you re-wrote the energy in a momentum way. I was not expecting this kind of complexity from this problem. In terms of computing, I think my issue is what would p^2 actually be in this formula. Thanks again for your amazing insight Floris.

Comment: In terms of Hippies, people should be proud to be Hippies. Because Hippies represent the values of being GOOD and promoting Freedom. It is through Hippies that America Ethical values improved.Also Jesus Christ was one of the first Hippies! And going back earlier was the Greek philosopher Socrates, earliest Hippie! Socrates always was not afraid to ask, people "Do you think that which you do is ethical!"

Comment: SO, since I believe in the ways of Socrates and Jesus Christ, I will ask "Is this just!" And if there is any retribution for asking, that goes to show the character of that other person!

Comment: The rearrangement is taking advantage of the fact that momentum is conserved - so we can see immediately that if the first mass is lighter than the second mass, then there will never be a case that the first mass is stationary. $p=mv=10 kg m/s$ in your case.

Comment: As for your other comments - I would recommend that we stick to physics.

Comment: Hi Floris, I will follow your advice to stick to physics, that was the main reason for me coming here. I am just surprised how when I ask a question on Physics.Stackexchange I run into this, this isn't the first they have done this to my questions. I find the Physics controllers here a bit odd, compared to other stackExchange places I have posted to.

Comment: Yes, your analysis and Algebraic rearrangement is very very insightful. So you are just rearranging this  based the total momentum of the system. This is really eye-opening for me, very interesting. SO I am going to go to my Pen and paper and try to derive the equation you put myself. If I run into problems, I will come back an ask you once more. Thanks so much for your GREAT wisdom Floris. So happy to meet someone so interested in physics such as yourself!

Comment: Hi Floris, I just did the computation using your formula and gives the same result as my approach. But your approach-formulation is much more insightful than my simple one, giving one the understanding of the relationship between the masses and their constraints of motion. I worked out the energy in terms of momentum eqn based on one mass.

Comment: Very glad to hear that you were able to develop a bit more insight!

Comment: Ok, I spent the last 15minutes plugging in p=ma*va, and did a lot of algebraic manipulations and the equation reduced to your original equation of the difference of energy between object-B and object-A.  So got deltaE = Eb-Ea.

Comment: This equation is quite amazing because of the subtraction of the 2 final energies lead to a negative energy in your first equation. I am reading your writing in the first equation to get an understanding of how you set it up. Thanks so much, a 1000 thank you's for your dedication to help. P

Comment: Hi, so now I see that you first used Conservation of Energy and included the spring, then you setup the Conservation of Momentum of the masses only(since the spring is considered massless). I was able to derive all that you have give me. After laying it all out, based on the Conservation of energy, the total energy , which is in mass B in the initial state where vb has 10m/s. We found from my first part that half of  B energy goes to object A in the final state which means the other half went to the Spring.

Comment: SO when I equated the Spring Energy to the Energy of Object A in the final state, I was actually correct, because the Spring gets half the Energy of B in the initial state which is equal to the Energy of object A in the final state. So Energy of Spring == Energy of Object A in the final state where Va=5m/s.

Comment: SO thank You Floris, You have led me to find the understanding I was looking for. I will put your answer as the answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes - I think you have understood it. Of course it was a coincidence (with the mass of A being twice the mass of B) that the amount of energy in the mass and the spring is the same; if A had been considerably heavier, more energy would end up in the spring (in the limit of A being a solid wall, ALL the energy would end up in the spring)

Comment: Yes, I was starting to think about changing the mass value to see how things would work. I will challenge some of my friends who have undergrad degrees in CompSci and Physics with this kind of question and variations of it. I am still amazed at how you came up with the Energy in terms of momentum for 2 bodies, that is not a very intuitive thing to come up with, and messy algebra to get it just right. Really appreciate the Equation Floris. Also I believe the authors who created this problem purposely choose these values for the masses in this way for Energy values to be nice integer multiples.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34394/discussion-on-answer-by-floris-two-object-connected-by-a-spring-momentum-energ).

Comment: Final point - if A is equal to B, the spring will be unstretched when B reaches zero velocity; and when A is lighter than B, then there will never be a time that B is stationary. That is the situation that corresponds to "imaginary x" - no solution because the condition (velocity of B is zero) used in the derivation of the equation is never met.

Comment: Thanks again Floris for your great devotion and giving further explanations on this. This problem I find to be really amazing, based on my University studies in Electromagnetism and in Quantum Chemistry, this particular question models a diatomic molecule(in quantum chem) and could be a model for a Electric Dipole in topic of Electricity and Magnetism. And we get into simple harmonic motion by modeling the Spring as a sinusoidal function. Using potential energy for a spring leads to quadratic potential, solving Quantum Schroedinger Eqn. I love this question. So profound!

Comment: @Palu thanks for your kind words. You might want to examine this question in the center of mass frame - it will give you another whole layer of insight. Simple systems are beautiful for growing your intuition.

Comment: Yes Floris, I like the way you phrased it: "Simple systems are beautiful for growing your intuition". These are the types of simple base models that universities should stress when covering topics. One should explore all the  different aspects, just as you mentioned with looking at its center of mass, before moving on to give more complex situation. It was thru discussions with you that I came to realize how this physical model here is the basis for a lot of things in physics and chemistry!!! It has been so great discussing these things with you Floris!

Comment: This is the kind of great philosophical discussions that I am looking for from Stackoverflow, this kind of back and forth we are doing is what the true ways of discussions in Science and Math and Philosophy. SO thank you for your great discussions and mentorship Floris, I really appreciate it. This is what Stackoverflow should all be about!